# subject of the term "be concerned with"

Tags: phrases, expressions

There is a paper with two authors. The paper is about topic XXX.
Which of the following is correct?

(A) The paper is concerned with XXX

(B) The authors are concerned with XXX.

A google search seems to show that (A) is very common and (B) is less common. Can the subject of the term "be concerned with" be either people or paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google search is not an authoritative evidence of usage. [This dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned%20with) shows that both uses are valid.

There is a fine (perhaps hair-splitting) distinction in meaning. Note that Merriam-Webster's second meaning is "about"; XXX is the paper's *topic*, but when applied to people, it expresses a conscious focus. If my paper is concerned with 18th-century plumbing, it takes it for its topic. If *I* am concerned with 18th-century plumbing, I have it on my mind. (While writing the paper, this is probably true, but still a different point.)

And just so we're clear, all this is separate from the phrase "concerned *about*" and other similar uses of *concern*. While writing the paper, 18th-century plumbing "is my concern," but if I discover 18th-century plumbing in my own home, it's a much more immediate *concern*.

Answer (score 0):

(B) I believe “the paper is concerned with” personifies the object, making it more a literary device rather than proper grammar.